# Encoding Apostrophe for Indy Call

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using Delphi XE and Indy 10.  I'm using `TIdHTTP` to make a call to a webservice, where a parameter contains the non-standard apostrophe:  `Bev’s` vs `Bev's`.

In urlencoded form, I am passing the parameter as: `Bev%E2%80%99s`

However the webservice is interpreting this as: `Bev%C3%A2%C2%80%C2%99s`

Relevant code:

```
idHttp.ConnectTimeOut := iTimeOut;
idhttp.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
```

Is there somewhere I have to specify that it is encoded a certain way?

Comment: Let Indy encode that parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`%C3%A2%C2%80%C2%99` is the urlencoded form of the UTF-8 encoded form of bytes `E2 80 99`, which in turn is the UTF-8 encoded form of the `’` character.  So, you have a double-encoding issue going on, where `’` is being encoded to UTF-8 twice before then being urlencoded.

The `hoForceEncodeParams` flag is used by `TIdHTTP`'s `SetRequestParams()` method, which is called by the overloaded versions of the `Post()` method that have an `ASource: TStrings` input parameter.

```
function Post(AURL: string; ASource: TStrings; AByteEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil): string; overload;
procedure Post(AURL: string; ASource: TStrings; AResponseContent: TStream; AByteEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil); overload;
```

If the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag is enabled, the strings are expected to be *unencoded* on input. `SetRequestParams()` will charset-encode them to bytes (based on the specified `AByteEncoding` parameter, where UTF-8 is the default), and then url-encode the bytes, eg:

```
idhttp.HTTPOptions := idhttp.HTTPOptions + [hoForceEncodeParams];
data := TStringList.Create;
data.Add('name=Bev’s');
idhttp.Post(url, data); // sends 'name=Bev%E2%80%99s'
data.Free;
```

If the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag is disabled, the strings are expected to be *url-encoded* on input. `SetRequestParams()` will not do anything to them, they are sent as-is, eg:

```
idhttp.HTTPOptions := idhttp.HTTPOptions - [hoForceEncodeParams];
data := TStringList.Create;
data.Add('name=Bev%E2%80%99s');
idhttp.Post(url, data); // sends 'name=Bev%E2%80%99s'
data.Free;
```

Comment: Thanks you for very detailed comment.  However I am doing a "Get" and not a Post.  On the Get I see the SetRequestParams method is not called.

Comment: @MSchenkel no, it is not, as a `GET` request doesn't send a body. The only parameters `GET` sends are in the URL itself, following an unencoded `?` character, eg: `http://host/path?params`. In which case, you are expected to pass a pre-urlencoded URL to `TIdHTTP`, and it sends it to the server as-is. If you pass `Bev%E2%80%99s` to `TIdHTTP`, that is how it this sent, not as `Bev%C3%A2%C2%80%C2%99s`. `TIdHTTP` does not decode and reencode URLs. You did not provide a [mcve] showing exactly how you are using `TIdHTTP`, though.